# Parse html string and append new div before every heading

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a variable who contain html return as a string coming from an API so something like this :

```
const myHTML = "<h2>Lorem</h2><p>ipsupm</p><h3>second header</h3><h3>third header !!</h3>"
```

How can I parse it and add a div like `"<div className="separator"></div>"` before every headings whether it's an h1, h2 or h3

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is:

1. use a RegExp to add the separator div before every heading (`<h[1-6]>`)
2. create a div and set its `innerHTML` to the new HTML string
3. append the new div to the body

```js
// 0. Original HTML string
const myHTML = "<h2>Lorem</h2><p>ipsupm</p><h3>second header</h3><h3>third header !!</h3>"

// 1. use a RegExp to add the separator div before every heading
const newHTML = myHTML.replace(/(<h[1-6]{1}>)/g, '<div class="separator"></div>$1');

// 2. create a div and set its innerHTML to the new HTML string
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = newHTML;

// 3. append the new div to the body
document.querySelector('body').append(container);
```

```css
.separator {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

If you want to exclude `<h1>` headings, you simply change

```js
const newHTML = myHTML.replace(/(<h[1-6]{1}>)/g, '<div class="separator"></div>$1');
```

to

```js
const newHTML = myHTML.replace(/(<h[2-6]{1}>)/g, '<div class="separator"></div>$1');
```

or any other range of headings (you got the idea).

Comment: I went for the second solution and it work like a charm so thanks a lot for this !

One question tho, I read that using regex on html is not proper coding is that right ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you (or whoever wrote that) mean with "proper coding"

Comment: Like it was "dirty code" and should not be done if there is another solution

Comment: I do not think there is a unique answer to that; I think it depends on the circumstances. I do not know why you have an HTML string as starting point, nor if it could be avoided but, once you have it, to me it looks more convenient adding the separator divs while working with a string (so you can use `String.replace()`) rather than immediately parsing the starting HTML string and then selecting all headings, looping through them and insert a div before each. If circumstances were different, probably a different solution would make more sense.

Comment: Ok thank a lot for your insight, you help me a lot ! :)

Answer (score 3):

`<div className="separator"></div>` you mean `class='separator`

```js
const myHTML = "<h2>Lorem</h2><p>ipsupm</p><h3>second header</h3><h3>third header !!</h3>";
const newmyHTML = myHTML.replaceAll('<h1>',"<div class='separator'></div><h1>").replaceAll('<h2>',"<div class='separator'></div><h2>").replaceAll('<h3>',"<div class='separator'></div><h3>")
console.log(newmyHTML)
```

Comment: This surrounds the headers with a div, instead of insert one before them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#browser_compatibility) to transform your string into DOM tree:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(myHTML, "text/xml");
```

And then operate on it the same way as on global `document`. To select all headers you can use `querySelectorAll()` method:

```
const headers = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3");
```

This method returns `NodeList` that implements `forEach` method to iterate over all selected elements.

For appending `div`s, `insertBefore()` method may be helpful. To use it, first you need to select the parent of a node before which you want to insert a new node (each node has a `parentNode` property) and afterwards, insert your `div`:

```
parentNode.insertBefore(yourNewDiv, headerNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an arbitrary element and add the string as HTML `.innerHTML` and manipulate it as you would otherwise do in the browser.

```js
const myHTML = "<h2>Lorem</h2><p>ipsupm</p><h3>second header</h3><h3>third header !!</h3>";
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = myHTML;

const headers = div.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3');

headers.forEach(h => {
  const separator = document.createElement('div');
  separator.className = 'separator';
  div.insertBefore(separator , h);
})

updatedHTML = div.innerHTML;

console.log(updatedHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you want to do it's easy :)

Just create a div element:

```
const divElement = document.createElement("div");
```

This element can now be added:

```
const myHTML = `<h2>lorem</h2> ${divElement} <p>ipsump</p>`;
```

I hope that's what you where looking for.

Comment: Nope. When you try to insert the newly created element into a string template, it will not be "converted" into its corresponding HTML code but to whatever its `toString()` method returns. With your code, the value of `myHTML` will be set to something similar to `"<h2>lorem<h2> [object HTMLDivElement] <p>ipsump</p>"` instead of `"<h2>lorem<h2><div></div><p>ipsump</p>"`